# This used to work before, but I changed something and now the URL and the Details View doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My goal is to make an hyperlink to a details view. When I click in a specific hyperlink for details, the URL automaticly is 0. It used to work, but from a day to another it just stopped working. I don't know if i changed something... I checked it a lot of times and it seemed alright.

Also, one thing that changed was that it usually showed the details of a specific record. Now it shows every record in the database. I changed my route map, but i already changed back to what it was. I already checked that the `@HTML.Action`is with the correct ID. I dont know what it is.

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id=0)
        {
            MovieViewModel[] movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModel
            {
                MovieID = movie.MovieID,
                MovieName = movie.MovieName,
                MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
                MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
                MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
            }).ToArray();

            return View(movies);
        }
```

This is the main movie view:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th><b>Nome </b></th>
            <th><b>Categoria </b></th>
            <th><b>Ano de Lançamento </b></th>
            <th><b>Descrição do Filme </b></th>
            <th></th>


        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.MovieName</td>
            <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
            <td>@item.MovieYear</td>
            <td>@item.MovieDescription</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes do Filme", "Details", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id = item.MovieID })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

This is the details view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th><h5><b>Id do Filme </b></h5></th>
            <th><h5><b>Nome </b></h5></th>
            <th><h5><b>Categoria</b></h5></th>
            <th><h5><b>Descrição</b></h5></th>
            <th><h5><b>Ano de Lançamento</b></h5></th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.MovieID</td>
            <td>@item.MovieName</td>
            <td>@item.MovieCategory
            <td>@item.MovieDescription</td>
            <td>@item.MovieYear</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

I don´t know what I changed, but this used to work before.

Comment: Yeah, that does not look right. Generally, the list of movies would be in an action like "Index" where you fetch a list/array and the view has a foreach to display each item. Details is generally just a single record so the Details action should fetch just a single record and the view displays it. Both your views display a list a of items.

Comment: But before, it was like this (the idea). Now, im completely missing a sentence or something like that and I cant remember.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/use-controllers-and-views-to-implement-a-listingdetails-ui). Also, do you use source control? That is essential if you break what once was working :)

Comment: I dont use source control. To be honest, im relatively new at mvc and at programming in general I dont know basic tools.

Comment: Take a look at the link. It has the basics of Index/Detail views.